# 80-bit floating point and subnormal numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754, x87

I am trying to convert an 80-bit extended precision floating point number (in a buffer) to double.
The buffer basically contains the content of an x87 register.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963055/msvc-win32-convert-extended-precision-float-80-bit-to-double-64-bit) helped me get started as I wasn't all that familiar with the IEEE standard.
Anyway, I am struggling to find useful info on subnormal (or denormalized) numbers in the 80-bit format.
What I know is that unlike float32 or float64 it doesn't have a hidden bit in the mantissa (no implied addition of 1.0), so one way to know if a number is normalized is to check if the highest bit in the mantissa is set. That leaves me with the following question:

From what wikipedia tells me, float32 and float64 indicate a subnormal number with a (biased) exponent of 0 and a non-zero mantissa.

- What does that tell me in an 80-bit float?
- Can 80-bit floats with a mantissa < 1.0 even have a non-zero exponent?
- Alternatively, can 80-bit floats with an exponent of 0 even have a mantissa >= 1.0?

EDIT: I guess the question boils down to:

**Can I expect the FPU to sanitize exponent and highest mantissa bit in x87 registers?**

If not, what kind of number should the conversion result in? Should I ignore the exponent altogether in that case? Or is it qNaN?

**EDIT:**

I read the FPU section in the Intel manual (*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1: Basic Architecture*) which was less scary than I had feared. As it turns out the following values are not defined:

- exponent == 0 + mantissa with the highest bit set
- exponent != 0 + mantissa without the highest bit set

It doesn't mention if these values can appear in the wild, nor if they are internally converted.
So I actually dusted off Ollydbg and manually set bits in the x87 registers.
I crafted ST(0) to contain all bits set in the exponent and a mantissa of 0. Then I made it execute

```
FSTP QWORD [ESP]
FLD QWORD [ESP]
```

The  value stored at `[ESP]` was converted to a signaling NaN.
After the `FLD`, `ST(0)` contained a quiet NaN.

I guess that answers my question. I accepted *J-16 SDiZ*'s solution because it's the most straight forward solution (although it doesn't explicitly explain some of the finer details).

Anyway, case solved. Thanks, everybody.

Comment: do you not have an 8087 unit at hand to do the job?

Comment: Probably going to need to ask somebody that knows assembler to put it  back in a regester that is associated with a particular variable.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I do but C++ (hence the tag) does not guarantee that long double is 80 bits in size. In fact, VC++ defines long double and double to be the same size (64 bits). Inline assembler seems like the only way to get a perfect conversions (there is code in the question I linked) but I prefer using plain C++, especially since there is no inline assembler in VC++ 64-bit.

Comment: The non-hidden initial `1` certainly makes it possible to write down bitpatterns that don't correspond to standard floats. I'm not sure if anyone is required to "normalize" those at some point. Surely a denormal would require the exponent to be zero.

Comment: @pezcode I think I'd be looking to receive the information in a more malleable format, i.e. double or a string.

Comment: @David Heffernan: The buffer comes like this from a Windows CONTEXT struct, I'm afraid there is no other feasible way to get that information.

Comment: Well, you're not going that get that info from IEEE and the Wikipedia quotes sure sound like nonsense.  Intel manual required.  Why don't you just convert it to double and *then* find out what you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SoftFloat](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html) library, it have `floatx80_to_float32`,   `floatx80_to_float64` and `floatx80_to_float128`. Detect the native format, act accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with finding information on sub-normal 80 bit numbers might be because the 8087 does not make use of any special denormalization for them. Found this on MSDNs page on [Type float (C)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd7199ke%28vs.71%29.aspx):

> The values listed in this table apply only to normalized
>   floating-point numbers; denormalized floating-point numbers have a
>   smaller minimum value. **Note that numbers retained in 80x87 registers
>   are always represented in 80-bit normalized form;** numbers can only be
>   represented in denormalized form when stored in 32-bit or 64-bit
>   floating-point variables (variables of type float and type long).

**Edit**

The above might be true for how Microsoft make use of the FPUs registers. Found another source that indicate this:

[FPU Data types](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_14/CH14-3.html#HEADING3-46):

> The 80x87 FPU generally stores values in a normalized format. When a
>   floating point number is normalized, the H.O. bit is always one. In
>   the 32 and 64 bit floating point formats, the 80x87 does not actually
>   store this bit, the 80x87 always assumes that it is one. Therefore, 32
>   and 64 bit floating point numbers are always normalized. **In the
>   extended precision 80 bit floating point format, the 80x87 does not
>   assume that the H.O. bit of the mantissa is one, the H.O. bit of the
>   number appears as part of the string of bits.**
>
> Normalized values provide the greatest precision for a given number of
>   bits. However, there are a large number of non-normalized values which
>   we can represent with the 80 bit format. **These values are very close
>   to zero and represent the set of values whose mantissa H.O. bit is not
>   zero. The 80x87 FPUs support a special form of 80 bit known as
>   denormalized values.**

Comment: I think the original motivation of the 80 bit FPU was that you can do 64-bit operations with greater accuracy, but you're always expected to interface via 64-bit floats. In that scenario, you would never create denormal 80-bit floats, because even the smallest 64-bit float is still a normal 80-bit float.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That doesn't mean it's impossible to feed it two 64-bit floats, calculate a little and get a result that even 80-bits can't hold in normalized form.

Comment: @pezcode: sure, but going back any 80-bit denormal value will be zero in the 64-bit representation, so that's not a problem, just underflow.

Comment: Though it hasn't been mentioned, I wouldn't be surprised if the design of 80-bit values was designed to allow for the possibility that an implementation might keep intermediate sums in a non-normalized format.  In a non-FPU implementation computing x-y+z, when all three values are of similar magnitude, being able to skip normalization after (x-y) could greatly improve performance.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) suggests there are denormal extended precision values too. My favourite language, Delphi, uses Extended as main floating point type and it has denormal values for them too.