# Convert 80-bit extended precision in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, extended-precision

I'm working on a programm which converts really old Open Access 4 .df Files into
other formats and also create Database scripts - I'm already able to convert every 
possible type except the decimal type. I found out that the byte order has to be a 80-bit extended precision. I allready tried to do the conversion by myself but I was not able to do the conversion from 80-bit extended precision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) to String and String to 80-bit extended precision in Java.

1. Example:

Value: 1,235

Hex from df File: 40 00 9e 06 52 14 1e f0 db f6

2. Example:

Value: 0,750

Hex from df File: 3f ff c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Maybe someone can help with the conversion?

Best regards

@EJP comment:
Ok I'm throwing away the last 16 bits so I got 3f ff c0 00 00 00 00 00 regarding to ([Java - Convert hex to IEEE-754 64-bit float - double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416269/java-convert-hex-to-ieee-754-64-bit-float-double-precision)) I try to convert it with

```
String hex = "3fffc00000000000";
long longBits = Long.valueOf(hex ,16).longValue();
double doubleValue = Double.longBitsToDouble(longBits);
```

But the result is 1,984375 and not 0,750

Comment: I don't know what 'binary String' means, but all you have to do is throw away the last 16 bits and convert the rest to `double`. Not difficult, and all doable within the JDK API.

Comment: @ Jean-François Savard - 
Long.valueOf(hex ,16) takes hex as input ;) so Long.valueOf(hex ,16) and Long#decode same result.

Comment: @EJP, you can't just throw away the last 16 bits because the format is different. Exponent is 15 bits in one and 11 bits in the other.

Comment: Just throwing away 16 bit doesn't look like a good idea - looking at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963055/msvc-win32-convert-extended-precision-float-80-bit-to-double-64-bit there is more to do

Comment: know a library? the question becomes off-topic, I suggest you [edit] into shape. You can ask help from the answerer if you do not know how

Comment: fyi: IEEE  80-bit extended `0x40009E0652141EF0DBF6` is `2.46913578` (exactly). And `0x3FFFC000000000000000` is `1.5` (exactly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it qualifies as an answer or whether it is possible to answer at all, because... Are you *sure* it's the standard 80-bit floating point format? Because as it is, it looks a bit strange. Take your first example:

40 00 9e...

Here, 0x4000−16383=1 is the exponent. The mantissa starts with the MSB `1`, which corresponds to the integer part, so it should have a form of 1,... x 2^1, which is greater than 2. But you say it should be 1,235. Doesn't make sense.

I've created this ugly hack in Java that sort of assembles the double:

```
long high = 0x40_00L;
long low = 0x9e_06_52_14_1e_f0_db_f6L;
long e = (((high & 0x7FFFL) - 16383) + 1023) & 0x7FFL;
long ld = ((high & 0x8000L) << 48)
          | (e << 52)
          | ((low >>> 11) & 0xF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFFL);
System.out.printf("%16X\n", ld);
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(ld);
System.out.println(d);
```

Assuming the input is correct 80-bit value, this fragment should work fine except it doesn't round properly, doesn't check for overflow, doesn't handle unnormalized values and probably fails to handle special values like NaN. For this input, it prints

```
4003C0CA4283DE1B
2.46913578
```

Not 1,235! Then I used this C++ code (compiled with GCC, where `long double` is in the 80-bit format):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long high = 0x4000;
    long long low = 0x9e0652141ef0dbf6;
    long double d;
    char *pd = (char*)&d, *ph = (char*)&high, *pl = (char*)&low;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        pd[i] = pl[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        pd[8 + i] = ph[i];
    }
    printf("%lf\n", (double) d);
}
```

It also prints 2.469136.

Comment: The OP might be from a locale that uses a comma as the decimal separator...

Comment: Hello,

thanks for the answer - tried your ugly hack with some values and yeah ... your result divided by 2 is the exact value ...

Comment: @Alnitak, I'm also from a locale that uses the comma, although I personally prefer the dot. But what does it have to do with the example? It's off by the order of 2, not by the order of thousands. No matter what locale is, one-point-something multiplied by two can't possibly be 1,235. The fact that it's off by 2 means that either the format is wrong or the conversion is wrong. And since C++ prints 2.46..., it means that the format is wrong.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov I have an converter decompiled with ida - i will check the values - maybe u are right - BUT it could be possible that the company  which developed Open Access 4 obfuscates the values of the .df file. There are no informations out there describing the meta informations in that df file etc.

Comment: @Sergey thank you your dirty hack is working - yeah you are right the format is not exactly right - but as I said every number (about 500k numbers) divided by two rounded by the HALF_UP on 3 digits is right.

Comment: @daTake, note that I screwed up the sign bit (used a wrong mask to extract it). Fixed that now.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov the question is now on hold as offtopic - I dont understand what I have to do - can u help me ?

Comment: @daTake, I don't know exactly. Surely, recommend-a-library type of questions are offtopic here, so you should edit it to make it more than that. Perhaps remove the library thing, make it instead an “I've tried this, but it doesn't work, anyone knows a reliable way to do it?” type of question.

Comment: Based on @SergeiTachenov 's answer a more generic code would thus be:
```
    public static double readExtendedFloat(InputStream is) throws IOException {
      ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(is.readNBytes(10));
      short high = bb.getShort();
      long low = bb.getLong();

      long e = (((high & 0x7FFFL) - 0x3FFFL) + 0x3FFL) & 0x7FFL;
      long ld = ((high & 0x8000L) << 48)
          | (e << 52)
          | ((low >>> 11) & 0xF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFFL);
      return Double.longBitsToDouble(ld);
    }
```